# JavaScript listener to call function on every request

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I'm trying to remove a element from dom in an online IDE using a simple chrome extension manifest_version : 2

content.js

```js
function removeWatermark() {
    try {
        let watermark = document.getElementById("watermark");
        watermark.innerHTML = "";
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
removeWatermark();
```

This is working fine when I open page for first time but when I change language its making a post request and the text is returning how to make the `removeWatermark` function to run on every httpresponse.

Comment: I have an idea, you can inject this css to the page when it loads: `#watermark{display:none !important;}`

Comment: Tq!!!! it working could you post it as answer

Comment: No need, it solves your needs, but it doesn't actually answer the question: trigger the function on every request  @THUNDER 07

Comment: Does it make sense to phrase it like this? You would like to remove it whenever it is added to the DOM. If so, I suggest you have a look at the MutationObserver class

Comment: I'm gonna close this question with a canonical duplicate along the lines of what axelduch said.